# Fast calculation of the size and counting all files in a directory and subdirectories using python (cross platform)

Tags: python, file, operating-system

How could i quickly calculate the size of a large directory while counting all the files in python cross platform, this is my current code but it is very slow on large file numbers(over 100000):

```
class filecounter:
    def count(self, scandir):
            global filescount
            global totalsize
            if not scandir[-1] == '/' or '\\':
                    scandir = scandir + '/'
            try:
                    for item in os.listdir(scandir):
                            if os.path.isdir(scandir + item):
                                    filecounter().count(scandir + item)
                            else:
                                    totalsize = totalsize + os.path.getsize(scandir +item)
                                    filescount = filescount + 1
            except WindowsError, IOError:
                    pass
```

The global is needed

Comment: Why not use `os.walk()` instead?

Comment: `if not scandir[-1] == '/' or '\\'` doesn't do what you think. Try `if scandir[-1] not in ('/', '\\')` instead.

Comment: P.S. The global is *not* needed if you coded this properly - have the function return both values as a tuple or list.

Comment: @user1469729 do you definitely need the to catch those exceptions? It will run faster without the try-except protection

Comment: P.P.S. You may be stuck. Since there's no function to return both the file names and sizes at the same time, you need to look up the size of each file. As a directory grows larger it takes longer for the OS to retrieve the size - a classic `n^2` problem.

Comment: i use os.walk() now instead of os.listdir() and os.path.isdir()

Comment: @NoelEvans Those exceptions are thrown if the program has no acces to  to the file or folder, which is has a lot of times when listing files for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for `os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) has almost precisely the sample you are asking for:

```
# from http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

Changing it to meet your needs is fairly simple:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
size = 0
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    size += sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files)
    count += len(files)
print count, size
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write portable code for file navigation, you should consider using the functions and constants from the `os` module (`os.path.join`, `os.pathsep`, `os.altsep`, ...).

One way you can optimise your code is to remove the recursion and the global variable by using the `os.walk` function, but it is not going to gain you much. You're going to be limited by the speed of the I/O of your computer.

```
def count(directory):
    totalsize = 0
    filecount = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            try:
                totalsize += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
                filecount += 1
            except OSError:
                pass
    return totalsize, filecount
```

Most of the time is going to be spent on syscall to get the list of file in a directory, and to get the size of a particular file. You could probably use python threads to parallelise the call of `os.stat` (indirectly called by `os.path.getsize`). For once, python thread would work as they release the GIL when doing a syscall.